# Hover div, show other div

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

```
<div id="quickstart">
    <asp:HyperLink ID="hlHemenBasla" runat="server">Deneyim Paylaş</asp:HyperLink>        
</div>
<div id="visiblepanel" class="visiblepanel"></div>
```

I have two `div`s on my website.

While I am hovering on `div#quickstart`, `div#visiblepanel` should be visible; at other times, it should not be.

I found some code on the internet, but I "couldn't run none".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First, make sure you're **NOT** *self closing* your `<script>` tags.

It should be:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="Scripts/jquery-1.6.2.js"></script>
```

**NOT**

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="Scripts/jquery-1.6.2.js"/>
```

*Then* to show/hide:

```
$('#quickstart').hover(function() {
    $('#visiblepanel').toggle();
});
```

[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/gmcalab/LhEUF/5/)

Comment: I tried and I found your codes on net but I couldn't run, I don't understand why didn't it run.. :S

Comment: @dmrc1143, I have included a running example on jsfiddle in the updated answer.

Comment: sir, You are right.
But I will be damned!
I couldn't run it.
There is:

   <script type="text/javascript" src="Scripts/jquery-1.6.2.js" />
   <script type="text/javascript">
       $('#quickstart').hover(function () {
           $('#visiblepanel').toggle();
       });
 </script>

<div id="quickstart">
        <asp:HyperLink ID="hlHemenBasla" runat="server">Deneyim Paylaş</asp:HyperLink>        
    </div>
    <div id="visiblepanel" class="visiblepanel" ></div>

Comment: Are you certain jquery is loaded? Are you getting script errors?

Comment: sir, I didn't get script errors.
it is here:    <script type="text/javascript" src="Scripts/jquery-1.6.2.js" />
   <script type="text/javascript">
       $('#quickstart').hover(function () {
           $('#visiblepanel').toggle();
       });
 </script>

Comment: The reason why it's not working it because you're self closing your script tags. This in not valid. Look at my updated answer.

Comment: Please mark this as the answer, if it answered your question.

Comment: sir, look at, still it is not working.
I did it, 
this is result: http://jsfiddle.net/mfbfj/

Comment: @dmrc1143: That's using MooTools - change it to jQuery. You also need to hide the element in the first place, preferably with CSS. See the first half of CSS in my answer..

Comment: Yes it works, change it to jquery... like so.. http://jsfiddle.net/gmcalab/mfbfj/2/

Answer (score 3):

If there are no other elements between `#quickstart` and `#visiblepanel`, you can do it like this with just CSS:

```
#visiblepanel {
    display: none
}
#quickstart:hover + #visiblepanel {
    display: block
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/aNTEA/

Answer (score 0):

Or, not using jquery:

```
<div id="quickstart" onmouseover="document.getElementById('visiblepanel').style.display='block'" onmouseout="document.getElementById('visiblePanel').style.display='none'">
    <asp:HyperLink ID="hlHemenBasla" runat="server">Deneyim Paylaş</asp:HyperLink>  
</div>
<div id="visiblepanel" class="visiblepanel"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Heres something.. http://jsfiddle.net/RuFXV/

HTML:

```
<div id="hoverThis">
    <span>This is just chilling here...</span>
    <p>...and this is shown when you hover over #hoverThis div</p>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
#hoverThis {
    float: left;
    border: 1px solid #e1e1e1;
    padding: 10px;
}

#hoverThis p { display: none; }
#hoverThis:hover p { display: block; }
```

Answer (score -1):

Use [jQuery](http://jquery.com/) and its hover and css methods

```
$('#quickstart').hover(
  function(){$('#visiblepanel').css('visibility','visible')},
  function(){$('#visiblepanel').css('visibility','hidden')}
);
```

Comment: The original question specifically called for the visibility property, so I don't know why answers referring to the display property are being voted up while this is being voted down.